# Change TabbedPage icon color

Tags: c#, .net, xamarin, maui

I'm developing a mobile software with **.NET MAUI** and my client asked me to change the icon and the background color of the navigation bar.

But my issue is the following: I'm not able to change the color of the icons in the page - I've tried to change on the **styles.xml**, on the **ContentPage tag** and using an image with the desired color. But it always stays with this gray-ish icon.

Is there anything that I'm missing to change this color?

This is my bar so far:
[image: Screenshot of the Navigation Bar]

This is what I've tried to change in the code:

Home Page

```xml
<!-- The color of the icone_home is already white -->
    <ContentPage Title="Início" 
                 BackgroundColor="#F1F1F1" 
                 IconImageSource="icone_home.png" 
                 Shell.TabBarTitleColor="Red" 
                 Shell.TabBarBackgroundColor="Red" 
                 Shell.TabBarDisabledColor="Red" 
                 Shell.TabBarForegroundColor="Red" 
                 Shell.TabBarUnselectedColor="Red">
        ...
    </ContentPage>
```

Styles.xaml

```xml
<!-- Yes, I`ve changed all the colors to test each one -->
<Style TargetType="TabbedPage">
        <Setter Property="BarBackgroundColor" Value="{AppThemeBinding Light={StaticResource White}, Dark={StaticResource White}}" />
        <Setter Property="BarTextColor" Value="{AppThemeBinding Light={StaticResource White}, Dark={StaticResource White}}" />
        <Setter Property="UnselectedTabColor" Value="{AppThemeBinding Light={StaticResource White}, Dark={StaticResource White}}" />
        <Setter Property="SelectedTabColor" Value="{AppThemeBinding Light={StaticResource White}, Dark={StaticResource White}}" />
    </Style>

    <!-- Did the same thing for NAVIGATION PAGE and SHELL -->
```

Any suggestion on where should I change? This app is iOS only.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding *Icons* you can try to use `FontImageSource` (eg in app.xaml) .

```xml
 <FontImageSource
            x:Key="SearchImageSource"
            FontFamily="FASolid"
            Glyph="{Static fonts:FontAwesomeIcons.MagnifyingGlass}"
            Size="22"
            Color="{AppThemeBinding Dark={StaticResource DarkFontColor},
                                    Light={StaticResource LightFontColor}}"

 />
```

Use in your `AppShell`

```xml
<ShellContent
    Title="Search"
    ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate views:SearchView}"
    Icon="{StaticResource SearchImageSource}"
    Route="SearchView" />
```

Or if useing `TabbedPage`

```xml
<NavigationPage Title="Two" IconImageSource="{StaticResource SearchImageSource}">
    <x:Arguments>
        <views:SearchView Title="Search" />
    </x:Arguments>
</NavigationPage>
```

For updating the font color of tabbed pages, it is all in the documentation for [TabbedPage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/pages/tabbedpage)

> **SelectedTabColor**, of type Color, indicates the color of a tab when it's selected.
> **UnselectedTabColor**, of type Color, represents the color of a tab when it's unselected.

```xml
<TabbedPage
    x:Class="MauiTest.Views.TestTabbedPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
    xmlns:toolkit="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2022/maui/toolkit"
    SelectedTabColor="Red"
    UnselectedTabColor="Azure">
```

...and for Shell [Tab appearance](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/fundamentals/shell/tabs#tab-appearance)

> **TabBarForegroundColor**, of type Color, that defines the foreground color for the tab bar. If the property is unset, the ForegroundColor property value is used.
> **TabBarUnselectedColor**, of type Color, that defines the unselected color for the tab bar. If the property is unset, the UnselectedColor property value is used.

```xml
<Shell.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="TabBar">
        <Setter Property="Shell.TabBarBackgroundColor" Value="LightPink" />
        <Setter Property="Shell.TabBarForegroundColor" Value="White" />
        <Setter Property="Shell.TabBarUnselectedColor" Value="DeepPink" />
    </Style>
</Shell.Resources>
```

Comment: Thanks! That did it!... Any sugestions on changing the font color?

Comment: See my updated answer. It is all in the documentation. If you find an answer helpful remember to upvote it so others can more easily find it.